# Nuget IVsPackageInstaller Hangs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, vsix

Using this code:

```
public void InstallPackage(Project project, string packageId, string version, string packageSource)
{
    var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
    var installer = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller>();

    installer.InstallPackage(packageSource, project, packageId, version, false);
}
```

When I try to install `EntityFramework 6.1.3`, for example, it simply hangs on the `installer.InstallPackage()` line. I've let it run as long as 10 minutes with no response, error, message, or any kind of indicator as to what's happening.

I've tried the following package sources:

1. https://nuget.org/api/v2
2. null
3. Downloading the package and referencing a local repo (e.g. C:\Nuget)

All with the same result.
The same thing happens with every package I tried (`Newtonsoft.Json`, `Unity`, etc.), so it's not just `EntityFramework`.

This is running in VS 2015 and .Net 4.5.1.
I've referenced the `NuGet.VisualStudio 2.8.6` package, but I've also tried 2.8.5 and 2.8.3 with no success.

Installing the package manually (through the NuGet package manager UI in Visual Studio) works as expected.

I've also tried the `NuGet.CommandLine 2.8.6` package, with the following implementation:

```
public void InstallPackage(Project project, string packageId, string version, string packageSource)
{
    var repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://nuget.org/api/v2");

    // Get the package install path
    var solutionDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(project.DTE.Solution.FullName);
    var path = Path.Combine(solutionDirectory, "packages");

    // Initialize the package manager
    var packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, path);

    // Download and unzip the package
    packageManager.InstallPackage(packageId, SemanticVersion.Parse(version));

    var projectSystem = new MSBuildProjectSystem(project.FullName);
    var localRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(path);
    var pathResolver = new DefaultPackagePathResolver(path);
    var projectManager = new ProjectManager(localRepository, pathResolver, projectSystem, repo);

    // Add references to project
    projectManager.AddPackageReference(packageId, SemanticVersion.Parse(version));
}
```

That downloads the package successfully, but fails to add the reference to the project with this error:

> "The 'AdaptiveTriggerLibrary 1.0.3' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60717.93'."

I'm not sure why it wants the `AdaptiveTriggerLibrary 1.0.3`, I assume it's a dependency of `EntityFramework`.

I tracked down a 3.1 beta NuGet.exe and referenced that. Turns out that the `IProjectSystem` interface was removed from the `MSBuildProjectSystem` class - and no alternative is available (that I could find), so I couldn't even get to a state where I could compile with that version. Seems pretty broken.

Any ideas?
All I want is a way for a `vsix` to install a nuget package to a project.